# Samsung Galxy S2 cracked touchscreen, need to access contacts

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, touchscreen

+I accidentally cracked my Samsung Galaxy S2 screen. I can't read the screen anymore. It would seem that the phone would work in every other way, if only was able to read and operate the screen. I looked up on the net for a replacement screen, but it is over $107.00. Not only don't I have that sort of money at the moment. But even if I did I would have to do all the taking apart and replacing of the damaged screen with the new screen. I found an awesome youtube instructional video that I can use once I get the money to buy the new touch screen. But I desperately need my contact details ASAP. I mean desperately. I have read where there is software that can do that sort of thing. But it also says that the phone needs to have been "rooted" I am not tech savy AT ALL. So any simple step by step instructions from anyone in the know would be so, so appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the contacts saved in your phone memory, SIM or Google account?

Comment: G'day I have removed my sim and the external memory card having found nothing on them. I suspect the details are on the motherboard. Don't understand the google reference.

Answer (score 0):

The S2 supports usb on the go i believe use a usb keyboard and mouse and you'll be able to use the device as normal without touchscreen functionality however dont hold me to this as wikipedia states the following

The micro USB port on this device also supports USB On-The-Go (USB OTG) standard which means the Galaxy S II can act as a 'host' device in the same way as a desktop computer in allowing external USB devices to be plugged in and used.[12] These external USB devices typically include USB flash drives and separately powered external hard drives. A video demonstration on YouTube[56] has shown the OTG function to be readily available with an ordinary micro USB (B-type) OTG adaptor. The same YouTube video goes on to mention a successful test completed on a 2 TB USB external hard drive (requiring own power source) but however reports of failure when trying to connect USB keyboards, tested USB mice and tested USB game pads. Currently the only file-system supported for USB drives within OTG is FAT32.

Comment: Sorry i didn't realise you said you cant read the screen if you could somehow get the screen to display on another device with a usb port booster adapter and a micro-usb to mhl-hdmi adapter or another way then it could be possible maybe! i'm currently trying to do something similar with my xperia z3, fortunately i can still read the screen but all touch functionality has gone.